# What does it mean for a curve to "enclose" points on a sphere?

Tags: algebraic-topology, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm studying index theory from Strogatz "Nonlinear Dynamics" book. In it, he asks a question about whether a closed curve contains fixed points with indices summing to +1 on non-planar surfaces. For the torus and cylinder, it's easy to show that the flow can contain only closed orbits, and thus no fixed points. However, for a sphere, there must be a fixed point (by hairy ball theorem). My problem is that I can't tell what it means for a path to "enclose" a point on a sphere. For a plane, it's easy, since a closed orbit will separate the plane into a bounded region and an unbounded one, to the bounded one is logically "enclosed". However, for a sphere, the two regions are both bounded, and could potentially be the same size. Does that mean that a closed path on a sphere "encloses" all points on the sphere that aren't on the path?

Comment: My guess is that it doesn't matter: a closed orbit corresponds to splitting the sphere into two disks, each having the vector field tangent to the boundary, and the sum of indices in each region will be the same.

Comment: Yes that's true. But if the entire sphere is counted, then it will have total index of 2, which is not the same as a plane.

Comment: I meant "it doesn't matter which of the two sides you pick."  I believe "enclose" is with respect to a choice of side.

Comment: I see, thanks for clearing that up.